# Equivalence between $\phi (z,s,a)$ and a sum of single impulses

Tags: fourier-analysis, trigonometric-series, transcendental-equations

A summed set of (negative) single impulses is given by

$-\sum_{R=0}^m \frac{\sin \pi (x-(R+1))}{\pi (x-(R+1))}$

Mathematica simplifies this to a function involving the Lerch Transcendent $\phi (z,s,a)$:

$\frac{\sin \pi x \bigl(\phi (-1,1,2-x)+(-1)^{m+1}\phi (-1,1,2+m-x)\bigr)}{\pi}$

But a plot of the two formulae with (randomly chosen) $m=25$ produces very different curves - blue is the single impulse, orange is the $\phi$ function:

[image]

Can anyone help explain this? Is it to do with transcendence? Is the 'simplification' algebraically manipulable?

Comment: It seems to work for integer values of $x$ but not for all other reals...

Comment: Correction: it seems *undefined* for integer values of $x$...